# Getting ready to learn html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm a desktop application developer, and I plan learning html5, but as it's not released, there are (almost) no published books and not too much infomation for beginners on the web... I feel I should start with html4 and the current web development skills.

I think I should start with html4, css, and javascript... but there are so many technologies related that I get lost :D So, what current technologies will be still used when html5 is released? I mean, what about "jquery" and "ajax"? I know they are javascript under the hood, but will they still make sense in the future?

What would you recommend me considering that I have just a little bit of html knowlegde, almost null CSS and completely null in javascript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) is solid, but it isn't really targeted at total beginners. You might want to check out [Designing with Web Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321616952) for getting a grasp on the basics of HTML/CSS. For the JavaScript side of things, I'd recommend [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748). Also keep an eye out for [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/), which is due this summer.

Answer (score 6):

If you're already familiar with HTML4, v5 is not terribly different, mostly it adds new elements and attributes, and removes some.

For essential coverage of web standards, I suggest Jeffrey Zeldman's [Designing with Web Standards (v3)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321616952). It's largely theory and background, with little code. I recommend it. There is a sister book by John Allsop, [Developing with Web Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321646924), which I have not (yet) read, but it is supposedly the implementation half of the topic the two books cover.

There is a book in the making by Jeremy Keith, [HTML5 for Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/), on the new A Book Apart site (backed by the people of An Event Apart, including Jeffrey Zeldman). Jeffrey writes about the new book [on his site](http://www.zeldman.com/2010/05/04/html5-for-web-designers/), and provides links to other related coverage, including Jeremy Keith's take on it.

Answer (score 5):

Get a good base with html/css then move onto javascript and pick a js framework that you like. Jquery seems to be most popular.

[Here's a good read on html 5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

Comment: What is the Ajax role? I mean... is like this:

*HTML : is the mark up, define the elements.
*CSS : style the elements.
*Javascript : allow you to interact with the elements in client side.
*Ajax : call to the server without reload???
    
Am I right?

Comment: @vtortola: Yeah, pretty much. AJAX is really just a particular way of using Javascript (specifically the `XMLHttpRequest` Javascript object) to transmit data to and from the server without making the browser go to a new URL or reload the existing URL.

Comment: Also, for a beginner it's probably a good idea to play around with plain Javascript and not involve libraries like jQuery until you start doing more complicated tasks.

Comment: @david au contraire... i didn't know anything about javascript until i started playing with jQuery. after getting familiar enough with how that worked, i eventually got more into the minutiae of javascript. my day job is about 90% client side scripting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be accomplished you need to approach JavaScript like a programming language and learn it in its own right, not as a simple way to script a few things. HTML4 is really pretty simple, CSS is where the meat lies really when *using* JS to manipulate pages.

I'd refresh on basic HTML, then start working with JS while trying to get to grips with CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Designing with Web Standards.  While not the best "beginner" book out there in terms of holding your hand through your first site build, reading this book is hands down the best way for you to establish a solid foundation of good habits so that when you do get to learning how to code you'll understand why it is important to do things the RIGHT way.

That being said.  HTML is cake.  Tying it into CSS is a creative challenge, and really being able to understand javascript will set you apart.

As far as technologies becoming irrelevant:  Stay away from Flash.  Other than that everything is as strong as ever.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this website [Technobits.net](http://www.technobits.net), which will give you a kick start morning with latest updates in your favorite technology. Check out following urls.

- http://www.technobits.net/technologies/html5-css/
- http://www.technobits.net/search/?q=html5

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is basically the same as HTML4 but with some nice additional little features. Pretty much everything you will learn from HTML4 will work seamlessly in a HTML5 environment.

I would start with learning things in this order: HTML4, then CSS2, then jQuery.

After that, start learning about HTML5 and CSS3 when more information comes out about them. But main issue about learning these languages falls down to your basic understanding. Once you have that in place, the newer technologies just make these basic things a bit easier.

Effectively, they will always be written and constructed in more or less the same way - but in time with newer versions, things will become increasingly easier to achieve.

Comment: You're not going to suggest he takes time to learn JavaScript, which is the mainstay of modern web client development?

Comment: I learnt jQuery before JavaScript. Whilst there might well be flaws in that process, jQuery is a much nicer and easier to understand method of introducing JS, as the traditional JS is very drawn-out and seems very daunting compared to the likes of JQ. If I ever need to, I can go back and look at the traditional methods, but I haven't had to yet :) After all, why learn the hard way?

Comment: "I learnt jQuery before JavaScript." You need to know Javascript to use jQuery so what you say is not possible.

Comment: If you don't have a _programming_ (HTML/CSS doesn't count) background jQuery will be a nice introduction into javascript. However, if you are already familiar with the concepts of basic programming (strings, booleans, loops, arrays, objects, if/else, etc) "learning" javascript from the ground up will be easy.

Comment: @jaanus actually, it's not. i did the same thing. One may eat a chicken without understanding how it came out of an egg.

Comment: @jason I think we understand differently what "learn Javascript" means. All jQuery calls are technically Javascript calls. Therefore, if you use jQuery, you use Javascript by definition. Thus, you must have learnt at least the very basics of how to do Javascript calls and what it means.

Comment: @jaanus correct, to a degree, but the argument could be made that all you're programming in C# or whatever language you prefer is just programming in binary, or assembler, or any language that your language abstracts. i don't have to KNOW binary to use it. i use C# instead. i didn't need to KNOW javascript to use it, i used jQuery instead. that's all i meant.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codecademy.com/ now has HTML, CSS, as well as lots of Javascript lessons - its free, online, and doesnt involve lots of annoying videos. It works for me anyways...