# Can some one expalin me whats basically HTML 5 and hows its different?

Tags: html

What are the main new features of HTML 5 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ready to learn html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782582/getting-ready-to-learn-html5)

Answer (score 1):

[Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) is a pretty good book (unfinished, as of this very moment) that does a great job of teaching the new features.

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) seems to cover it pretty well...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources on the internet:

- [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)
- [HTML5 differences from HTML4](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Google I/O 2010 Keynote from Day 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a46hJYtsP-8); it gives a basic overview of HTML5, and showcases many of the features that HTML5 adds. Basically HTML5 enables HTML and JavaScript to do many of the things desktop applications have been able to do, but in a way that is standardized across browsers and doesn't require any browser-specific hacks or plugins in order to implement.

Comment: also the keynote from Google IO 2009 is full of HTML5 demos - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5aJAaGZIvk